# CSS3 animation/keyframes doesn't work in IE11

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, internet-explorer-11, keyframe

I have a few svg elements that I'd like to change their fill colors with a css animation. It works in Chrome and FireFox but not in IE11. Any ideas?

```
.particleColor {
    -moz-animation-name: colorChange;
    -o-animation-name: colorChange;
    -webkit-animation-name: colorChange;
    animation-name: colorChange;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -o-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   }
```

---

```
  @-moz-keyframes colorChange {
    from {
        fill:transparent;
    }
    to {
        fill:powderblue;
    }
     }

@-webkit-keyframes colorChange {
    from {
        fill:transparent;

    }
    to {
        fill:powderblue;
    }
   }

@keyframes colorChange {
    from {
        fill:transparent;
    }
    to {
        fill:powderblue;
    }
}
```

---

It's really this simple but if more detail is needed please ask (I can't post this as it is cause stackoverflow says I should be more specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, IE currently doesn't support CSS animations of SVG.

Comment: I see, apparently they'll ship it with edge when it comes out.          Thanks.